# How to fix text going out of grid item in reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

When the text is too long, it is going through the grid box, how can I shift the text to the next line if the text is too long? The description text needs to be in separate lines as it is going beyond the width of the grid item, How can I achieve that?

[image: The]

----------------------parent component javascript-------------------

```
import React from 'react'
import Notesdata from '../Data/Notesdata'
import Notescard from './Notescard'
import "../Styles/Notes.css"


const Notesview = () => {
    const data = Notesdata
  return (
    <>
    <div className='notes'>
{
    data.map((item) =>{
        return <Notescard item={item}/>
    })
    
}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Notesview
```

----------------------parent component css-------------------

```
.notes {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px;
  /* grid-row: auto auto; */
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  margin: 350px 200px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

----------------------child component javascript-------------------

```
import React from "react";
import "../Styles/Notescard.css";

const Notescard = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <div className="content">
        <h3 className="item">{item.title}</h3>
        <h4 className="item"> {item.tagline}</h4>
        <p className="item">{item.description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notescard;
```

----------------------child component css-------------------

```
.box{
    background-color:#333;
    /* padding:20px; */
    border-radius:10px;
    color:#fff;
    display:flex;
    align-items:space-between;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    font-family:sans-serif;

}

.content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    column-gap: 300px;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    margin-left: 30px;

}

.item{
    margin-top: 70px;

}
```

Comment: It is hard to say without sandbox, but I think you need to set width of item.

Comment: try to set an max-width for the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set 100% width to your item class